# New Tile with special start of application in WP7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone, live-tile

I've got question. I have application which is a phone book. I would like to create Tile (in Windows Phone main screen) which'll call that number after I click Tile on main screen.

Is that possible? What should I do to make something like that? I can create custom Tile or maybe I should create some method after my application start?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the live tile with something like the following code:

```
string number = "000 - 000 000";
ShellTile tile = ShellTile.ActiveTiles.FirstOrDefault(t => t.NavigationUri.ToString().Contains("phone=" + number));

if (tile == null)
{
   StandardTileData tileData = new StandardTileData();
   tileData.Title = "Call " + number;
   ShellTile.Create(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml?phone=" + number, UriKind.Relative), tileData);
}
```

And then override the OnNavigatedTo in MainPage.xaml, and add the following code:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
   if (NavigationContext.QueryString.ContainsKey("phone"))
   {
       string number = NavigationContext.QueryString["phone"];
       PhoneCallTask task = new PhoneCallTask();
       task.PhoneNumber = number;
       task.Show();
    }
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
}
```

If you have not done it yet, you also need to add the `"ID_CAP_PHONEDIALER"` capability in the `WMAppManifest.xml` file, or you will get an exception when calling `task.Show();` above.

Now you got a live tile that when clicked will launch the application and call the number (The user must still confirm it in a dialog though, and that is something you can't disable)

Comment: That's the way I should do it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a flip tile and the using something like this:

http://blog.ecofic.com/?p=406

Write the number to isolated storage then when they click the tile you read the isolated storage and call the number.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Mangopollo library from CodePlex to create a secondary live tile: http://mangopollo.codeplex.com/